# Microsoft translator api ajax callback is asynchronous and thus isn't filling response in their respected textbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, callback

I haven't had much of experience with ajax calls (Specifically with api's and javascript) . 
I am using Microsoft translator API with ajax  . In it I am calling a callback function in following way :

```
        ac.push(tgtId);

        s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate" +
        "?appId=Bearer " + encodeURIComponent(token) +
        "&from=" + encodeURIComponent(src) +
        "&to=" + encodeURIComponent(tgt) +
        "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(elem.value) +
        "&oncomplete=mycallback";
```

Issue I am facing is that,  I  either want to make this call sync or pass a parameter in callback function . So that , my code would remember that inreturn of which request, I am getting response in callback method.

Currently, I tried , maintaining an array named "ac" and pushed id into this array sequentially after each request and then got id by using following code in callback method .

```
  function mycallback(response)
{
id(ac[0]).value=response;
ac.shift();

}
```

However, this approach doesnt works as , ajax call is asynchronous.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, No specific answer has been mentioned yet. Here is a fix I did for my site.

I converted my code to jquery and set an async value to false.